# Android Development - My Separately Built Database Insert Class Doesn't Work

Tags: java, android, database, android-sqlite, sql-insert

I've created an Android app that uses SQLite for the Database.

I have an SQLiteOpenHelper class and my db insert code (I used ContentValues) is in my main activity class. **It all works perfectly**, but the database(rows) is **huge** so I decided to move the insert code into a new separate class, a new class meant for only inserting rows into DB in order to have some clarity and simplicity in my project. Which I did, but it doesn't insert into the Database, and when I try reverting everything and having the insert code back into my Main activity, it works, but when I move it to the separate class then it doesn't.

My Insert class looks something like this:

```
package com.darlingtinho.translator;

import com.darlingtinho.translator.FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

class DbInsert {
public void insert(SQLiteDatabase db, String word, String phonetics, String phonetics2) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_EN_WORD, word);
    values.put(FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PHONETICS, phonetics);
    values.put(FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PHONETICS2, phonetics2);
    db.insert(FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
}

void foo(Context context) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = (new TwiDbHelper(context)).getWritableDatabase();

    insert(db, "abomination", "abort", "story");
    insert(db, "add", "bad", "good");
    insert(db, "acts", "frog", "jog");
}
```

}

The above class doesn't work which I find baffling, Please point out what am missing for the class to successfully insert those rows into my DB. Immediate assistance would really be appreciated please.  Thank You

Comment: `class DbInsert { /* code here */ }`

Comment: yep, but my question is focused on what is suppose to go into the class in order for it to still insert those rows into my DB. @zapl

Comment: That's up to you. A good class has a clear responsibility and encapsulates it. The open helper for example is a great encapsulation for "opening an sqlite file while creating / upgrading when necessary". http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html#databasetutorial_project the DAO / DataSource structure isn't bad

Comment: I have made my question more clear now added a dummy class, hope you understand me now. @zapl

Comment: you can start by avoiding repetition: http://pastebin.com/w2TVPek0 - look at the code, identify the part that changes and the part that stays the same and then put it in a method.

Comment: Wow, thanks so far, sorry am quite new to Java, Android Dev. and OOPs in general so some of my questions might be very novice oriented. So would like to ask this before we continue, in creating this new class on Eclipse, do I really have to put something in the Superclass..I cleared the java.lang.Object and left it blank is that okay? @zapl

Comment: Now my question is very narrow, and straight to the point..@zapl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it doesn't work because you're writing code such as `values.put(FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_EN_WORD, "add");` in the class body rather than inside a method. Try putting all that code in the constructor like:

```
class DbInsert {

    final SQLiteDatabase db = (new DbHelper(this)).getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values;

    public DbInsert(Context ctx) {
        db = (new DbHelper(ctx)).getWritableDatabase();

        values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_EN_WORD, "add");
        //.... etc...
    } 
}
```

Comment: did that, now no more syntax error, it runs alright, but it doesn't work, it doesn't insert anything.